# unable to run the program throwing error

Tags: java

For some reason it throws error. Could some one help me in fixing this?

```
package com.assignment;

public class TravelService {
    public class traveller{
         String trvName = "Dan Brown";
         int trvage = 24;
         int trvId = 3435;

        if(trvID == 3435){
            System.out.println("Name of the traveller is " +trvName);
        }
            else{
            System.out.println("No ID found!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: you can't put the `public class traveller` inside the `public class TravelService`. Use one file per class only. (There are private classes that you can put inside the same file with another class, but that's just *bad design*)

Comment: please, its a very easy answer if you search a little on google... try an hello world before starting coding...immagine if all people ask for this...no research was made here sorry

Comment: also you didn't write the code inside a method.

Answer (score 4):

You need to place the code inside a method, not inside a class. Use the `main` method as an entry point for the program. Java is also case-sensitive, so change `trvID` to `trvId`.

```
public class TravelService {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String trvName = "Dan Brown";
     int trvage = 24;
     int trvId = 3435;

       if(trvId == 3435){
          System.out.println("Name of the traveller is " +trvName);
       }
        else{
        System.out.println("No ID found!");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the need to put your code in methods, Java variable names are case sensitive. So `trvID` is not defined because it does not match `trvId`.

Comment: very good point, but could you add this as a comment instead of an answer?